# How to check condition with JSP variable?

Tags: java, jsp

Hello  i am New jsp i want to check condition in jsp. whether value is null or not.?
i have write following code in jsp page

```
   <% String s = request.getParameter("search"); %>
    <%=s %>
    <% if (<%=s ==null) { %> 
     <div>textbox is empty</div>

   <% } else { %>
   <div>textbox value..
    <% } %>
```

i get textbox value  in variable if textbox value is null then it should display first message othervise second. 
tell me how to do?

Comment: By the way, the best practice is to avoid using scriptlet in your jsp. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Comment: This is more of a syntax problem - I think once Rajan gets his answer, the question ought to be deleted.

Comment: your question say if textbox value is null then execute `if` otherwise `else`? what is your textbox value? value of s ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    <% String s = request.getParameter("search"); %>
    <%=s %>
    <% if (s==null || s.isEmpty()) { %> 
     <div>textbox is empty</div>

   <% } else { %>
   <div>textbox value..
    <% } %>
```

Comment: if i dont insert value in text box then also it also go to else part

Comment: @Rajan can you check what value of `s` is printed? it might not be `null` but empty `""` or having spaces. check modified answere..

Answer (score 9):

The best way to do it is with [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnake.html). **[Please avoid scriptlets in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)**.

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${empty search}">
   <div>textbox is empty</div>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <div>textbox value is ${search}</div>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 3):

Does it even compile? `<% if (<%=s ==null) { %>` should at least be

```
<% if (s == null) { %>
```

If you want to check for empty string as well, do

```
<% if(s == null || s.trim().length == 0) { %>
```

Comment: <% if (s==null) { %>
<div>Condition is true!</div>
<% } else { %>
<div>Condition is false</div>
<% } %>

Comment: it always goes to else part

Comment: Then the String is not null.

Comment: my string is null... i dont enter any value to text box

Comment: Your if test says otherwise. Even though it doesn't have a visible value doesn't mean it have to be null.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28785/discussion-between-rajan-and-nilsh)

Answer (score 2):

```
<% String s = request.getParameter("search"); 
     if (s ==null) { %> 
     <div>textbox is empty</div>

   <% } else { %>
   <div><span><%=s%></span></div>
    <% } %>
```

**edited to include empty string**

```
<% 
       String s="";
     if(request.getParameter("search")!=null)
      {
          s=request.getParamater("search");
      }
     if(s.trim().length()==0)
        {%>
           <div>Empty Field</div>
        <%}
          else{%>
              <div><span><%=s%></div>
           <%}%>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<% String s = request.getParameter("search"); %>
    <%=s %>
    <% if (s ==null) { %> 
     <div>textbox is empty</div>

   <% } else { %>
   <div>textbox value..
    <% } %>
```

Comment: hello alpesh Gediya ... it also go to else part

Answer (score 0):

In `jsp`, it is easy to check whether a `variable is empty or not`.

```
String search;
if(search.isEmpty()){
out.println("The variable is empty ?");
}
else{
out.println("The variable is Not empty ?");  
}
```